# iphone app: how to renew an expired distribution certificate through the iOS provisioning portal

Tags: iphone, ios, certificate, provisioning

My distribution certificate is tied to an app, that I have distributed ad hoc to number of field employees, and it says it's going to expire tomorrow.  When I go into the iOS provisioning portal, I go to the certificates link, and then the Distribution tab.  Under expiration date for the certificate the date is listed as tomorrow.  My question is how do I renew the certificate?  I've been told there may be a renew button that pops up when it expires.  I've also been told this renew button is going to pop up today when it hasn't. Is there going to be a renew button?  Will the renew button pop up under the provisioning profile attached to the certificate or in certificates-->distribution in the portal?  None of this is documented anywhere on what I need to do to ensure no down time with my app.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Once expired, you will get a renew button, yes. If you want to do it before it expires, revoke the current certificate and you will get a button to request a new one.

Which ever way you do it, your ad hoc app will stop working tomorrow and you should distribute a new build with new provisioning profile signed with new certificate.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Finally, an answer that is helpful on this subject.  Apple support was zero help on this.

Comment: FYI, the renew button never appeared.  So I just deleted the old provisioning profile.  Created a new certificate.  Created a new provisioning profile and attached it to the new, non expired, certificate.  Then I put it in my keychain and rebuilt my project with the new embedded mobile provisioning profile.

Comment: I get the renew button, but it doesn't work.  Just throws a "No value was provided for the parameter 'certificateIds'" error.  Obviously there's not even a location to put in any parameters...

Comment: I also got the "No value was provided ..." error when trying to renew.  All documentation says Xcode will do everything for you, but for me, not until I deleted all of my old profiles from both Xcode's Organizer and also the Provisioning Portal itself.  After deleting, creating new ones worked.

Comment: That is weird. I handled all of this via Xcode organizer when extending my developer programs earlier this year and had no problems there.

Comment: Same error 'No value was provided for the parameter 'certificateIds'.'

Comment: How long was the turnaround for most of you?

Comment: @RenatoLochetti this is quite an old answer. If you have problems with renewing your certificates, I suggest you post a new question. But you should be able to do all of that automatically with Xcode now.

Comment: @Filip My distribution certificate is going to expire in 30 days, I got a mail from apple team. since my app is in app store with this certificate and i don't want to release new version with new certificate. Is there any way that my current certificate will be renew and I should not publish new version. please help me

Comment: @sandy AppStore apps are signed with Apple's certificate once published on the store, not individual's. You got nothing to worry about. If you renew your program, app will stay on sale for another year and will not require any update of certificate.

Comment: @FilipRadelic thanx to reply soon, just need one confirmation that, My developer program having validity upto next year, but the certificate which i attached with market build going to expire in 30 days, so 1) I can renew my certificate from portal ? 2) once I renew should not re-publish a new build ion market ?-- please

Comment: @sandy 1) yes, you can renew your certificate from the portal, or from Xcode (it will ask you to do that automatically when it expires) 2) no, you don't have to re-publish the app, it's automatic.

Answer (score 1):

From the [apple developer support center certificates section](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/certificates/):

> **iOS Distribution Certificate (In-house, Internal Use Apps)**
>
> Users will  no longer be able to run apps that have been signed with this certificate. You must distribute a new version of your app that is signed with a new certificate.

Comment: Is that also the case for Apps distributed with Testflight?