# Making an app for a single iPad

Tags: ipad

I'm looking for some clarification on developing for a single iPad. I have an app in the app store, however I want to make my own app for personal use that won't be submitted to the app store.

Is it possible for me to develop the app and get a certificate to "test" the app on my iPad, and just keep it on? I don't want to have to pay $299 for an enterprise account to publish private apps for a single iPad to use the app!

I've had a read about and I'm probably more confused now than I was before!

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Gary

Comment: If you don't mind renewing the certificate every now and then, you can do this with an ad-hoc distribution certificate.

Comment: Ad-Hoc distribution only expires once a year. Thats not too difficult.

Comment: Even the enterprise account expires once a year.  Just use the Ad-Hoc you already have on your current account

Answer (score 1):

If you enter the iOS Developer Program (99$ a year), you will be able to do what you mention: you will be able to generate a certificate and a provisioning profile and install the app on your device (actually, up to 100 devices).

The only thing is that you will need to create a new certificate/provisioning profile and rebuild/reinstall your app when the certificate expries.

Answer (score 0):

No matter how you do it, you will always have to sign your app to be able to run it on a device.

All Provisioning Profiles expire, except the ones for the App Store (which you can't use without publishing your App in the App Store). So paying $299 for an Enterprise Account wouldn't even help you [in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270989/ios-enterprise-provisioning-profile-expiration).

However, if you want to run the App only on this single device, you could consider jailbreaking it. This would allow unsigned apps to run.