# in how many days the provisioning profile expires in paid accounts?

Tags: app-store, provisioning-profile

I know the provisioning profile expires in 7 days on free accounts.but what about paid accounts.Individual/Enterprise. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: see this once it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270989/ios-enterprise-provisioning-profile-expiration

Answer (score 1):

1 year.

Source: I have paid account

Answer (score 1):

It will expire in **1 year**.
Provisioning profile expires with the Individual/Enterprise account expiration.