# Do I have to release a new iOS version every year using Enterprise Licensing?

Tags: ios

We released an iOS app for our company on AppCenter using the Enterprise License.  Even though my enterprise license has to be renewed every year which I've been doing, somehow my app seems to have been allowing people to download and install it for several years now without me having to do anything.  I did rollout an update to the app a year ago so maybe that contained an updated provisioning profile, I can't remember.

All of a sudden this week I'm having issues with people installing my app and I noticed the cert was expired in the provisioning profile so I edited the provisioning profile and selected the newest cert which expires in 2021.  Still the users can't download my app so I'm guessing I have to rebuild my app with this updated provisioning profile and roll out an updated version.

I've checked similar SO articles like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270989/ios-enterprise-provisioning-profile-expiration) but all of the answers are confusing.  They say the provisioning profile expires in a year but the enterprise license expires in 3.  Then others say you have to remove the old provisioning profile from the device but some of these answers are from 8 years ago so it makes me wonder if this is still true.

I have 3 questions:

1) When a new year rolls around and my existing provisioning profile now has an expired cert, should I delete this provisioning profile in the Apple Developer console and create a new one or simply edit the profile to include the new cert?  If I am supposed to delete the existing profile please explain why because I heard someone else say this but I can't see any reason why.

2) On an on-going basis from year to year and to in order to support new users downloading my app, should I roll out a new version of my app every year that includes the new and/or updated provisioning profile, or every 3 years, or something in-between?

3) Do I have to delete old provisioning profiles off of the device?  Please tell me no!

Comment: When you cert expired do not delete and create, you need to edit expired one.

If you already deleted old one you can always resign you app without creating a new build, like that -  https://coderwall.com/p/cea3fw/resign-ipa-with-new-distribution-certificate

Comment: Review [this WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/705/)   - you need to update the provisioning profile before it expires; if you use an MDM you can push a new provisioning profile for the existing version. If not then you need to release a new build. When the certificate expires you need to release a new build. You should see if you can migrate to a B2B app; it is easier to manage than enterprise