# Renewing iOS Developer Enterprise Program

Tags: iphone-developer-program, enterprise-distribution

What happens if you don't renew your enterprise program after the first year? Do the apps distributed stop working?

Comment: have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216485/how-to-manage-enterprise-distribution-certificate-expiration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provisioning profile that allows you to install an app on the devices will expire, and you won't be able to renew that profile without your membership. You can see the expiration date in the Settings app on your device.