# Is it possible to deploy the App to the client permanently?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, deployment, ad-hoc-distribution

I have developed an App for my client and now I need to deploy it to him within his company, I have learned that, we need to make mobile provisions on Apple's developer portal,include the devices in it, so the App can be run on that particular device.

Also, if the period of our developer account expires we have to renew it.. in order to let the App work normally on the device.

But i want to know if there is any way the App can be deployed to the client permanently.. ? i.e once we handover the App to the client, he need not to come to us again.. and use it for as much time as he wants .. ?

Also, please note that the device that the client is using in NOT jailbroken ..!

Comment: no, it is not possible, your client have to renew its license in order to keep the app working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create Distribution provisioning profile which currently have validity of one year, that means your application will run on clients device for one year without your effort.

After one year, you need to reattach by creating new profile. This can be done very easily from console.

Visit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216485/how-to-manage-enterprise-distribution-certificate-expiration).

Answer (score 1):

App that users download from App Store will continue working even if the developer of that app doesn't renew his subscription.

See [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html) So the solution for you is. Upload the app on app store. Let your client download it. Once he download it even if your apple certificate expired he can continue to use the app.

However, once your apple distribution profile is over then your client won't be able to download the app from app store.

Comment: Here one point to be noted is that it will be available to all people

Comment: P.J is right , since the App will be used internally ..Uploading the app to store wont be appropriate.

Comment: @Shailesh there must be some login or something for the app?

Comment: @Rushi:The App deals with uploading the files on the FTP server, so not login but the FTP credentials will be required.

Comment: Will it be a first page of your application? If yes then you can go ahead and upload your app on Appstore. Cause without this credentials no one can use your app.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not the first page, there are two more features in it..  @Rushi.

Comment: @Rushi If you are putting login page and restricting users, Apple can initially approve application, but after bad reviews, Apple may review  your application and reject it from Apple App Store as its for limited users. App Store applications are only for all people and not for specific users..

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is using Apples Business-to-Business App Store. This allows you to specify which clients can download the app. The app is otherwise handled just like a normal app store app and does not expire.

The ad-hoc distribution you referred to is not suitable for distributing apps to clients. Anytime a device changes or is added you'll have to re-provision it and re-issue it.

One other alternative is to have your clients get an Enterprise developer license. The app would still have to be renewed every year but they could install it on any device and better yet, you would not have to have it reviewed by Apple.

Comment: Does Apple reviews the Apps, that are uploaded on B2B store .. ?

Comment: Yes but the review process is a little different and recognizes that this app is for one company and not the public.