# Does deleting certificates and provisioning profiles from developer.apple.com influence itunes connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I want to delete as much as possible from [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/) (certificates, provisioning profiles, ...), but I don't want to mess up the apps that I have submitted to app store using these certs and profiles.

So does [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/) influence iTunes to get connected? What may and what surely won't happen if I mess up things in [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The certs and profiles are necessary for packaging your app for debug on a device or for submitting your app.
It has nothing to do with your iTunes Connect.

As long as you have a valid, paid Apple Developer account, nothing will happen to your apps.

Comment: The certs must be keep valid as "Certificate Validation". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216485/how-to-manage-enterprise-distribution-certificate-expiration

Comment: but how can I still push new release if all these things got deleted, how does the app store identify the app?