# Renew / Revoke ios distribution certificates - effect on ad-hoc users

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning

My distribution certificate is about to expire and I would like to know:

If I revoke it and create a new one, will my current testers' apps stop working?

These testers are using a version of the app build with an ad-hoc provisioning profile.  These are not app-store version, but test version.

I'm assuming they will continue to work normally since the certificate isn't validated every time they use the app, but I want to be sure before I revoke it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216485/how-to-manage-enterprise-distribution-certificate-expiration

Comment: Thanks.  I saw that link but wasn't sure if the same applied to Enterprise apps as Developer apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version on their devices will run until the installed profile expires. It should only affect applications that are not installed yet and will be installed by the old ipa. Only the new ipa with the new profile is able to be installed after rejection.

So far my experiences with it

Comment: everything went well? Or were there any unexpected problems?

Comment: This has been postponed until next week. I'll let you know how I get on.

Comment: Thanks geo! So, if I revoke my distribution certificate, need to renew the adHoc provisioning certificate, right!? But do I need to release (create new ipas) new versions whit the new provisioning certificate? The ipas released before will not be valid to install??
Thanks

Comment: Basically, What happens to the ad-hoc apps NOT installed??

Comment: "Only the new ipa with the new profile is able to be installed after rejection. " ;) your old ipa will try to verify against the server with an old cert. Haven't tried it in last time, but this is the logic. You are signing your apps with a profile, and in this profile the cert is contained. And if you try to verify with a rejected cert, you will fail. The validation is also only done on installing, so after installation you can use it on

Answer (score 2):

Has this been done?  What happened to the ad-hoc apps already installed when you revoked your team Distribution Certificate?

Comment: What happens to the ad-hoc apps NOT installed??

Comment: From my testing, if an IPA is signed with a revoked certificate you will not be able to install it any more.