# Apps in the enterprise appstore after provisioning profile expires

Tags: ios, app-store

I have an app in enterprise appstore and the provisioning profile with which I created iPa is due to expire next month. If I go to developer account and renew the provisioning profile, what happens to the app in appstore which was created with old provisioning profile? Should I create a new iPa with new renewed provisioning profile and submit it? Is it enough to just renew the expiring provisioning profile or should we renew, create iPa with new one and upload it to appstore again?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens to my Enterprise apps after my Enterprise developer account membership expires?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45237387/what-happens-to-my-enterprise-apps-after-my-enterprise-developer-account-members) - not exactly the same question but contains similar examples of profiles and certificates expiring.

Comment: Thanks Wez. I have valid enterprise developer account and valid distribution certificate. Only my provisioning profile expiring next month. What will happen to the apps already in the enterprise appstore  if I renew them before it expires is my question?

Comment: Can you be clear what you mean by 'enterprise appstore' - AFAIK there is only one AppStore. Are you using a thidparty like Beta (by crashlytics) or Hockey App to distribute enterprise provisioned builds?

Comment: Exclusive for our enterprise in house distribution using MDM.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to provide a new provisioning profile, that has a new expiration date, to the devices with your app or existing installations of the app will stop working.

You can do this by packaging a new version of your app that includes the new provisioning profile and then having your users install the update.

Alternatively, if your devices are managed by an MDM (which is best practice) then you can have the MDM server push the updated provisioning profile to the devices. The advantage of this approach is that it doesn’t require any user action.

The process of certificate and provisioning profile expiration is explained quite well in [this WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/705/)

As an example, [here are the instructions for Microsoft InTune](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/intune-classic/deploy-use/ios-mobile-app-provisioning-profiles)