# Will enterprise app be invalidated on expiration/revocation of push certificate and/or provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, certificate, push, provisioning-profile, enterprise

I have an enterprise app that has a push certificate that is expiring in a week. We don't actually use this push certificate as we already use the push key. This Push Certificate is linked to the App ID though, and I am afraid that revoking the Push Certificate will invalidate the Provisioning Profile and invalidate the app on all my users' devices. I am aware that this happens when you revoke the Distribution Certificate, but what happens when the Provisioning Profile is invalidated for an active enterprise app?

Comment: Check this will this help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216485/how-to-manage-enterprise-distribution-certificate-expiration)

Comment: My question is more about what happens when the Provisioning Profile is invalid. Will that block access to the app in any way?

Comment: The push certificate is independent of the provisioning profile. If the provisioning profile expires then the app stops working, but an expired push certificate won't affect the provisioning profile

Comment: But when I click Revoke on the certificate in Apple's Developer portal it tells me that it will invalidate the Provisioning Profile it is linked to. Will letting it expire (instead of revoking) keep the Provisioning profile intact?