# iOS Developer and Distribution certificate expiring while app in Test Flight

Tags: ios, certificate, testflight

I deployed a application to itunes it's currently in beta testing (Test Flight), in few days Developer and Distribution certificates will expire, should i continue to submit app store even after expire my certificates or re-create the certificate and re-build the app and submit?

Answer (score 1):

You should have to recreate the distribution certificate or renewal it...because expired certificate not accepted by apple INC.

Check the link to renewal [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096254/iphone-app-how-to-renew-an-expired-distribution-certificate-through-the-ios-pro)

Comment: But, the final version app is now in iTunes (not uploading new one), and it's ready to submit, but i'm holding it because of content copy right. please confirm, should i re-create and rebuild the app with newly create certificates and upload to iTunes.

Comment: if the distribution app is expired you have trouble to place the app in itunes .....

Comment: if the app is already in itunes means renewal it ...its not a big deal to renewal so don't worry about it